# Mailchimp REST API Subscribe Validation Error "Struct" Angular Resource

Tags: javascript, api, angularjs, mailchimp

I'm stuck... I've been trying to get Mailchimps API to work with Angular Resource. I got as far as getting past the initial validation errors, but email is asking for a struct??

I have no idea what to do.. Here's my current solution..

```
// In controller
this.saved = MailChimp.save({

            email:$.param({
                email: user.email,
                euid: '1',
                leid: '2'
            })
        });

// In module service
myModule.factory('MailChimp', function($resource){
return $resource('https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json', {
    apikey: 'ac07bec21c8560d088b95888aab219fb-us7',
    id: '27749',
    email: '@email'
},
{
    save: {
        method: 'POST'
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "JSNOP" Method as your are calling cross domain URL:

below is the example from angular site

Buzz client
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

and jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

```
 save: {
        method: 'JSONP'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reader,
I did not find a fully working angular module so i make one.

Try that: https://github.com/cgarnier/angular-mailchimp-subscribe